# Load balancer unable to contact a server through http

Tags: iptables, http, load-balancing, connection

In our infrastructure we have a load balancer(apache mod_balancer) and three backend servers that run apache as a web service and iptables as firewall, Lately ONE of them is giving a lot of " (110)Connection timed out: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to 10.0.0.15:80 (www.domain.com) failed" I checked the connections between this server and the load balancer through different port (9999) and it was working perfectly

I switch load balancer to contact the backend server through its public IP and the timeout error disappeared, which prove that the problem is not in backend apache server.

I tried to make the load balancer to get a file through port 80 from that backend server and it failed as well.

UPDATE :

`<Proxy Balancer://cluster-fcgid lbmethod=byrequests timeout=10 maxattempts=2 >

        BalancerMember http://backend.domain.com   loadfactor=1 retry=30 max=130 timeout=40 

        BalancerMember http://backend2.domain.com  loadfactor=1 retry=30 max=90 timeout=40`

</Proxy>

The thrid backend server has the same configuration but I couldn't added it because of restrictions.

UPDATE :

## the firewall table

*filter 
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0] 
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0] 
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0] 
:MYFIRE - [0:0] 
-A INPUT   -j MYFIRE 
-A FORWARD -j MYFIRE 
-A MYFIRE -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A MYFIRE -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED            -j ACCEPT 
-A MYFIRE -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport ssh  -j ACCEPT 
-A MYFIRE -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport https  -j ACCEPT 
-A MYFIRE -i eth1 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport http -j ACCEPT 
-A MYFIRE -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT 
-A MYFIRE -j DROP 
COMMIT

What could be the source of the problem ?
Any hints are greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your mod_balancer config?

Comment: I have added the configuration in the post

Comment: Can you post a redacted output of `iptables-save`?

Comment: The two look ok but the third is the one you were having trouble with, right?  is there any way to post the info for the third balancermember?

Comment: The thrid backend member is BalancerMember http://backend3.domain.com loadfactor=1 retry=30 max=130 timeout=4 ..

Comment: Is it timeout=4 or timeout=40?

Comment: THe timeout is 40 ,, I have changed the following line in the iptables "-A MYFIRE -i eth1 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport http -j ACCEPT " To "-A MYFIRE -i eth1 -p tcp --dport http -j ACCEPT " And it worked fine .. Can someone explain it to me why the timeout stopped now ?